# Retrofit 2.0 beta1

Tags: retrofit

```
public interface AppApi 
{
        @GET("/api?action=" + ApiManager.API_USER)
        Observable<JsonObject> getUser();
}
```

whith `Retrofit 2.0 beta1` .I can't get the Response?

Retrofit 2.0 beta not supprot Observable,now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

now an adapter for RxJava is required.

you can get the message from [changeLog](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-200-beta1-2015-08-27)

> New: CallAdapter (and Factory) provides extension point for supporting multiple 
>   execution mechanisms. An RxJava implementation is provided by a
>   sibling module.

try following code and problem may be solved.

in app/build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
```

in your java code (like your activity)

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(YOUR_END_POINT)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .(other options.....)
    .build();
```

Now you will works with RxJava

Comment: Here's how you add an adapter: Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())

Comment: Take a look at great article about new retrofit http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Answer (score 2):

You could write it this way.

```
public interface AppApi {
   @GET("/api")
   Observable<JsonObject> getUser(@Query("action") String api_user);
}
```